# State of static variables in a WAR file calling Native.loadLibrary("somec++.so")

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am tasked with renewing very old code, written in Java which interfaces with c++ native code using Native.loadLibrary method. Whole Java implementation is packed into a .war file and served on Tomcat server.

Here is the interface→

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public abstract interface Validator extends Library {
    public static final Validator instance = (Validator)Native.loadLibrary("libValidator.so", Validator.class);
    public abstract int validate(int para1, byte[] data, int para2);
}
```

libValidator.so has static variables all over. When there is a request to server the following code is called→

```
int response = Validator.instance.validate(gameMode, data,length);
```

What I am  curious is if there are many requests to the web server the state of the static variables in  libValidator.so will be shared between requests?

I come from a .Net background so in case of P/Invoke the answer would be yes.

Comment: Yes. Native code will share static variables. There is no easy way to avoid this. Simplest is create separate process for each call (will be SLOW). You have to refactor native code.

Comment: @talex, Just as I expected. The shared object will be loaded once and if there are many requests, the static variables will be shared... I guess there is no other option but to refactor the library itself :(